# How to send location (longitude and latitude) through onreceive() function?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms, location

I have an application which needs to send location on receiving a sms.My problem is how to send location since I'm inheriting broadcastreceiver class and can't inherit MapActivity to make use of locationmanager to get location.(Multiple inheritance not allowed in java).Can anyone give me idea of how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

In `onReceive`, you get a reference to your app's contect object.
So you can get it this way:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

The LocationManager has nothing to do with MapAcivity. You can get a reference to it anywhere you got a context object (Any activity/service, and in BroadcastReceiver onReceive method, and other places too.)

Comment: I changed my code.Now it's working but instead of sending its own location it's sending the received message back again.Why is it so ?

Comment: Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/53ZJH3iN If you want to see any other file(like .xml ) Please let me know,I'll post it here.

Comment: First of all, you really should give meaningful names to variables. It's hard to read this... And you have not fixed what I suggested - Your code wouldn't even compile now. I think you should change it and make it more human readable, then fix the problems.

Comment: This is my code after fixing the problem as suggested by you http://pastebin.com/yKitMftU and with it I'm giving an explaination which can help you to go through the code easily(sorry for that variable names I can't change them now beacuse they are used in other places but I'll try to keep their names human readable in future). Starting from the start I have some public static variables which I'm using to create a list view of received sms's,so they might not be of your concern,following it I have locationManager,longitude and latitude.After that in onReceive function,cont...

Comment: I'm extracting the address and body of received sms."str" variable contains a string of sender + message body."str2" is a variable which contains sender's address which I'm using in sendTextMessage to autoreply the received sms."str3" is a variable containing string to compare the autoreply condition(I have used a variable Request_Accepted to check when to reply back)."msg" is a variable containing a string of longitude and latitude which I'm joining with my " autoReplyToken " and storing this value in "autoReplyText" and sent to sender.

Comment: Now the problem is instead of sending it's location,it's sending sender's message(which contains sender's location) to sender.If you have any other doubt please ask me and give me some idea where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Let me understand. We have person A, B. A sends to be a message starting with "autoReplyToken", so B automatically sends back to A its location?

Comment: A sends to B a message which contains his location, so B automatically sends back to A its location and attaching "autoReplyToken" in this message so that A doesn't send back to B(basically purpose of "autoReplyToken" is to prevent looping of sms's from A to B and vice-versa repeatedly).Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need multiple inheritance here, you can just *delegate*: An instance of your broadcast receiver can simply call methods on another object, e.g. an `Activity`.

An *inner class* can be used to do that, so that you'd have the code for the receiver and for your Activity in the same class, if that's what you want.

Ex.:

```
public class MyActivity extends MapActivity {

  protected class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // ...

    void someMethod() {
      MyActivity.this.doSomethingInActivity( value );
    }

  }


  protected void doSomethingInActivity(Object param) {...}

}
```